# Element UI not showing data from fetch-suggestion <el-autocomplete> vue js

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I've been switching from el-select remote search to remote search input el-autocomplete. My problem the data are not showing in the dropdown.

```
<el-autocomplete
v-model="searchValue"
:fetch-suggestions="getData"
placeholder="Type here"
loading="loadingCascade"
</el-autocomplete>
```

VueJS in methods code

```
getData(searchString){
            if (searchString !== '') {
                this.loadingCascade = true

                setTimeout(() => {
                        this.$API.Public.getData(searchString)
                        .then(res => {
                            let result = res.data
                            let resSearchList = result.data
                            //Include search data
                            let arr = {id : searchString, name : searchString}
                            resSearchList.unshift(arr)

                            this.searchList = resSearchList.name
                            
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                        })
                        .then(_ => {
                            this.loadingCascade = false
                        })
                    
                }, 500);
            }

        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Method must have callback function. Change `getData()` method something like:

```
getData(searchString, cb) {
  if (searchString !== '') {
    this.loadingCascade = true

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.$API.Public.getData(searchString)
        .then(res => {
          let result = res.data
          let resSearchList = result.data
          //Include search data
          let arr = {
            id: searchString,
            name: searchString
          }
          resSearchList.unshift(arr)

          this.searchList = resSearchList.name
          cb(this.searchList); // call callback function to return suggestions
        })
        .catch(err => {})
        .then(_ => {
          this.loadingCascade = false
        })

    }, 500);
  }

},
```

You can look at the usage [here](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/input#autocomplete)

Comment: like this ```const results = [this.$API.Public.getData(searchString)]```?

Comment: If `this.$API.Public.getData(searchString)` returns an Array, just `const results=this.$API.Public.getData(searchString)` is enough.

Comment: The important thing is to fill results according to the API, and call callback function for this results

Comment: still not working, cannot display the item name on the fetch suggestion

Comment: Could you add  `console.log(results)` before the line `cb(results)`, and share the output of the console.log?

Comment: I have edited the answer, please take a look again.